# Matlab - import data tool

Tags: matlab

i have got a problem with the import data tool in matlab.
I just installed matlab this morning, at first it worked. However after shutting down the computer once, it doesn't work anymore.

More specifically, it opens and load data from .txt or spreadsheet, but when i click to import data to my workspace, instead of showing the progress in the waitbar it shows an error message:

> IMPORT TOOL - couldn't find waitbar handles

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the import tool works as intended until it cannot find the wait bar. A [waitbar](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html) is a loading progress bar, which is available every basic installation of MATLAB (no toolbox required). Either the waitbar is created (do you see it?), but somehow not passed correctly through a broken connection between the import tool and the waitbar, or the waitbar function wasn't installed correctly.

I conclude your installation wasn't finished properly, so: uninstall MATLAB and reinstall it in one go (without pausing the installation).

You could also provide the system details you're installing on and the MATLAB version. Maybe someone knows of a certain condition of your particular setup that might cause the problem.